# предполагается наличие идентификатора строки или числа ie

Tags: jquery

Во всех браузерах, кроме IE код работает хорошо, но в IE выдает ошибку "предполагается наличие идентификатора строки или числа". Никак не могу разобраться, в чем проблема.

```
function saveDraftToIBlock(input, iBlockID, sectionID) {
    Fingerprint2.getV18(function (result) {
        var serializedData = {
            userID: result,
            iBlockID: iBlockID,
            sectionID: sectionID,
            [$(input)[0].name]: $(input)[0].value // ошибка тут
    };
        var url = '/ajax/form_saver.php';
        var type = 'post';

        syncAjax(
            url,
            type,
            serializedData,
            function (result) {},
            function (error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    });
};
```

Comment: вопрос решился.

Comment: Каким образом решился? Если не секрет.

Comment: @Mikhail, скорее всего тем, что IE не поддерживает computed свойства

Comment: @Grundy, интересует именно IE - пока остановился на транспилировании кода с помощью Babel...;
Быть может существуют более элегантные решения?

Comment: @Mikhail, либо так, либо не использовать вычисляемые свойства

Answer (score 1):

Пока остановился на транспилировании кода с помощью Babel...
Быть может существуют более элегантные решения?

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну ответ же...

Comment: @Qwertiy по-моему, больше тянет на комментарий.

Comment: стоит дописать, что IE не поддерживает computed свойства. и привести пример кода-аналога для IE (хотя бы результата транспиляции) - иначе ответ будут сносить

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var serializedData = {
>   userID: result,
>   iBlockID: iBlockID,
>   sectionID: sectionID,
>   [$(input)[0].name]: $(input)[0].value // ошибка тут
> };
> ```

```
var serializedData = {
  userID: result,
  iBlockID: iBlockID,
  sectionID: sectionID,
};

serializedData[$(input)[0].name] = $(input)[0].value;
```